# Calculate all possible combinations of given characters to a given length

Tags: python, passwords, combinations

I'm trying to make a program that calculates all possible combinations of given characters for `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890`... but only for 8 spots so like, `AAAAAAAA`, `AAAAAAAa`, `AAAAAAaa`...

Something like this as a start:

```py
for i in xrange(999999999):
    print ''.join(['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'[j]

for j in [(i//d)%36 for d in (63,54,45,36,27,9,3,1)]])
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code? We are able to best answer your question if it is clear, concise, and specific.

Comment: It's been awhile since I've taken discrete mathematics but if my memory serves me correctly you have 218 trillion combinations in this set..... this would take like a couple days to calculate on an average computer... If you still want to go through with this you'll need to be more specific on what you need. Are you having trouble with the math and algorithm behind this? or trouble implementing a data structure to hold 218 trillion objects?

Comment: @BrennenSprimont I'm have trouble with the code. I updated my question to show what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mystring = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'
from itertools import product
combos = [''.join(i) for i in product(mystring, repeat = 8)]
type(combos)
```

Returns a list of combinations.

Comment: Nice but maybe some thing like this but larger for i in xrange(81):
print ''.join(['abcd'[j]
for j in [(i//d)%3 for d in (27,9,3,1)]])

Comment: I changed it to mystring = 'AB'
from itertools import product
combos = [''.join(i) for i in product(mystring, repeat = 2)]
print combos and now it is working but it prints out as ['AA', 'AB', 'BA', 'BB'] how could i make it without the brackets, quotes, and commas.

Comment: having it on a different line would be best. It would be okay if it has spaces.

Comment: It is creating a list.  The single quotes indicate that they are strings.  And the comma indicates where the item in the list ends/begins.   You can iter through a list.  Do you not want a list?  What type of object do you want?

Comment: Yes I would like a list

Comment: It is a list.  Try      type(combos)     as I put in my last edit.  Good luck, I think you have what you need.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably take a while to run since there are a lot of possible permutations. So just know that beforehand. My solution:

```
from itertools import permutations

options = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'
possibilities = [w for w in permutations(options, 8)]
```

This will make a list of all the possible passwords stored in the possibilities variable.

Comment: I got a error like this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*****/Documents/untitled", line 4, in <module>
    possibilities = [w for w in permutations(options, 8)]
MemoryError

Comment: It's probably because there are so many permutations that you're running out of memory. Like @Brennon Sprimont said there are a huge number of possible permutations.

Comment: I tried to shorten it to > options = 'AB' and nothing happens.

Comment: did you change the 8 in permutations to 2?

Comment: add `print possibilities` so that you can see the list

Comment: now it's working. How could I make it without the brackets, commas, and quotes. eg. it comes out like this [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A')]. how can I make it like AB BA?

Comment: It doesn't print out AAA, BBB, and CCC. Also, when it make it ABCD12345 it prints out 9 characters instead of 8.

Comment: This is incorrect, this doesn't give you all possibilities. You need to use intertools product in order to get the 62^8 possibilities

Answer (score 0):

My little generator algorithm:

```
def combinator(karakterler, uzunluk):
    l = len(karakterler)
    for i in range(l ** uzunluk):
        s = ""
        for j in range(uzunluk):
            i, index = divmod(i,l)
            s += karakterler[index]
        yield s

for i in combinator("abc",3): print(i)
```